# How to select last index value in drop-down by?

Tags: javascript, dom, drop-down-menu

How does one read and select the last index value in the drop-down by using Javascript?

A sample of the HTML.

```
<select name="unqiue">
  <option value="number:1" label="1">1</option>
  <option value="number:2" label="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  <option value="number:3" label="3">3</option>
  <option value="number:4" label="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Drop-down values may differ, I need to pick and select last value 4.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have done any searching or reading up on the subject? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+select+option

Answer (score 2):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll('select[name="unqiue"] option:last-child')[0]](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

Example:

```js
var lastOpt = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="unqiue"] option:last-child')[0];

//
// To select this element:
//

lastOpt.selected = true;

//
// To get the value
//

var val = lastOpt.value.replace(/\D*/, '');

console.log(val);
```

```html
<select name="unqiue">
    <option value="number:1" label="1">1</option>
    <option value="number:2" label="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="number:3" label="3">3</option>
    <option value="number:4" label="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Upvoted, but they want the value, not the element html ;)

Comment: @Archer Thanks so much. They want also to select that element.

Answer (score 0):

You're example seems to suggest that `name` is a unique value for a [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) in your markup.

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to acquire this item, then read or manipulate it.

```js
const unique = document.querySelector('select[name="unqiue"]');
const valueLast = unique.lastElementChild.value;
console.log(valueLast);
const textLast = unique.lastElementChild.textContent;
console.log(textLast);
unique.selectedIndex = unique.length - 1;
```

```html
<select name="unqiue">
  <option value="number:1" label="1">1</option>
  <option value="number:2" label="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  <option value="number:3" label="3">3</option>
  <option value="number:4" label="4">4</option>
</select>
```

[ParentNode.lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild)

[Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

[HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

[HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)